# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: while running tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, integration-testing

trying to run a test but end up in the error in title. i am working in a springboot project. the project works fine without issues. when i try to run the test, it is throwing the error.

added the dependent ValidationService class in the test folder

inside java package

```
@Service
public class ValidationService {

    @Autowired
    TicketDetailRepository ticketDetailRepository;


    public boolean isValidTicket(Long ticketId)
    {
        Optional<TicketDetailEntity> optionalTicketDetailEntity = ticketDetailRepository.findById(ticketId);
        if(optionalTicketDetailEntity.isPresent())
        {
            return optionalTicketDetailEntity.get().getTicketStatus();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/xxx")
public class ValidationController {

    @Autowired
    ValidationService validationService;


    @RequestMapping("validate")
    public ValidationResponse validate(@RequestBody @Valid ValidationRequest validationRequest) {

        return true;
    }

}
```

inside test package

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @WebMvcTest(controllers = { ValidationController.class }, secure = false)
    @Import(ExceptionHandlerConfiguration.class)
    public class ValidationControllerIntegrationTest {


        @Autowired
        MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Autowired
        ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        @Autowired
        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter;

     @Test
        public void xxx() throws Exception {
            ValidationRequest validationRequest = ValidationRequest.builder().build();

            jsonPost("xxx", validationRequest)
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("xxx").value(true))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("xxx").value(false));

        }

ResultActions jsonPost(String url, Object entity) throws Exception {
        return
                this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .post(url)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(entity))
                )
                        .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
    }
}
```

Expected : Should not throw error
Actual : throws unsatisfied dependency error while running test.

Comment: Need to see exception details.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the full error. It is not clear which bean is not initialized. 
One suggestion is to add @ComponentScan on your test class for ValidationService.

like
    @ComponentScan ({"PACKAGE_NAME_WHERE_ValidationService_IS_Resides"})

Answer (score 0):

You need mock the Service layer code. You can use `@MockBean` annotation.

```
@MockBean
private ValidationService service;
```

[Example Integration Test1](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing)

[Example Integration Test2](https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/5684146-create-web-applications-efficiently-with-the-spring-boot-mvc-framework/6157116-make-services-unit-testable-using-dependency-injection)